# Switching screens using Kivy: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transition'

Tags: python, class, user-interface, inheritance, kivy

I've run into an `AttributionError` when trying to call a "screen switch" function defined in one class from another using kivy library in python.

The structure of my code is as follows:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.app import App

def init_grid(width, height, mines):
    global grid_field
    global flagged
    # Initiate the gird field with empty grids
    grid_field = [[ClassA() for i in range(width)] for j in range(height)]
    flagged = 0
    ...


class Main(App):
   def build(self):
      sm = ScreenManager()

      current = Current(name="current")
      screenA = ScreenA(name="screenA")
      screenB = ScreenB(name="screenB")
      ...
      ...

      sm.add_widget(current)
      sm.add_widget(screenA)
      sm.add_widget(screenB)
      ...
      ...

      sm.current = "current"
      return sm

...

class ClassA():
    # a class my code is at when the error arises, 
    # which is not the starting "current" screen class 
    # but a different class that serves a certain purpose to my program
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        ...
        self.button = Button()
        self.button.bind(on_touch_down=self.method)


    def method(self, instance, touch):
        if (a condition):
            ScreenA().change_to_B()

    ...




...


class ScreenA(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Screen.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        ...
        ...
        init_grid(10, 10, 10)

    def change_to_B(self):
        self.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        self.manager.current = "screenB"


...


class ScreenB(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Screen.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        ...
        ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

The error message is:

```
in change_to_B
     self.manager.transition.direction = "left"
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transition'
```

From my code above, I defined the screen-switch function `change_to_B` in class `ScreenA`, and I called this function in class `ClassA`. I have inherited the `Screen` parent class in the both classes `ScreenA` and `ScreenB` I have created. But strangely enough, the error message seems to suggest that the object `screenA` is a `NoneType` object, which shouldn't be the case as I have declared that to be screen object when creating the class by inheriting the `Screen` parent class.

Can anyone point out what is the mistake I am missing out? Thank you in advance!!!

EDIT:

I think I need to make clear of my code. So I'm basically trying to write the minesweeper game and the `ClassA` is the grid that the gameboard of minesweeper consists of, and it has a `Button` attribute to implement the clicking function `method` (shown in the code above). In the clicking function `method`, I was trying to call the screen-switch function `change_to_B()` defined in class `ScreenA`, which is a screen object declared in the build method of the ScreenManager (I think).

The flow of the code is: Current(name="current") (which is irrelavent to this question) --> ScreenA(name="screenA"), where `ClassA()` is created in the global list variable from function `init_grid()` --> ClassA(), where clicking on the UI calls the function binded to the `Button` attributes of the `ClassA()` objects.

The `ClassA` object is created in a function `init_grid`, where a global variable `grid_field` is created to store the `ClassA` objects in a 2D list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common mistake - you use more than one object of each screens, so you add one object to `ScreenManager` and that object has property `manager`. But then you create another object of `ScreenA` class here:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        ...
        ScreenA().change_to_B()
```

Screen Manager knows nothing about that object. So the thing you should keep in mind is that you add `objects` to screen manager, not `classes`.
You didn't provide the whole code so I don't know where you define the object of `ClassA` class, but you should pass object from `build` method there to make it work. Something like this:

```
class ScreenA(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Screen.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        ...
        ...
        # here we pass the object of the ScreenA class (which is self) to init grid to be able to pass it to ClassA
        init_grid(10, 10, 10, self)

# add object to arguments
def init_grid(width, height, mines, screenA):
    global grid_field
    global flagged
    # pass the object to ClassA
    grid_field = [[ClassA(screenA) for i in range(width)] for j in range(height)]

class classA():
    # don't forget to add object to arguments
    def __init__(self, screenA, **kwargs):
        ...
        ...
        self.screenA = screenA

    def method(self, instance, touch):
        if (a condition):
            self.screenA.change_to_B()
```

Or with global variables:

```
current = Current(name="current")
screenA = ScreenA(name="screenA")
screenB = ScreenB(name="screenB")

class Main(App):
   def build(self):
      sm = ScreenManager()

      global current
      global screenA
      global screenB
      ...
      ...

      sm.add_widget(current)
      sm.add_widget(screenA)
      sm.add_widget(screenB)
      ...
      ...

      sm.current = "current"
      return sm

class ClassA():
    def method(self, instance, touch):
        global screenA
        if (a condition):
            screenA.change_to_B()
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. But can I double check that is it ```class classA()``` or ```class ClassA()```? Also sorry for the ambiguity of my code above but the line that calls the screen-switch function is under another method binded to the ```Button``` attribute of ```ClassA``` when clicking, instead of ```__init__()```. I tried adding the classA object in the ```build()``` function of ```ScreenManager``` but yet it gives me the NameError "screenA is not defined"...

Comment: @DanielQiao show me where do you create the object of `ClassA` so I'll be able to edit my answer

Comment: Hi sorry for the trouble but I have included the function that creates the ```ClassA()``` object and where the function is called (in ```ScreenA```), as well as the workflow of my code.

Comment: @DanielQiao I've edited my answer, check the code there. So there we pass the object of ScreenA class from that class to `init_grid` method and from there we pass it to ClassA. A little bit weird but in your case it would be like this. Or you can use other way and use global variables. It would be more simple I think.

Comment: Sweet! It has successfully resolved my problem and the global variable approach is more straight forward and clean! Thank you so much!!!!!!